# Cochains: terminology

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, homology-cohomology

Let a real, smooth manifold $M$ be given.  Let $C_k(\mathbb Z, M$) denote the set of $k$-chains with integer coefficients, and let $C_k(\mathbb R, M)$ denote the set of $k$-chains with real coefficients.

As far as I can tell, the set $C_k(\mathbb Z, M)$ is  module over $\mathbb Z$ while $C_k(\mathbb R, M)$ is a vector space over $\mathbb R$.  We can then consider their duals, the module $C^k(\mathbb Z,M)$ and the vector space $C^k(\mathbb R, M)$ respectively, and elements of both of these sets are called cochains, the former being cochains with integer coefficients, and the latter being cochains with real coefficients.

**Question.** Is there a name for $\mathbb Z$-linear functionals $f:C_k(\mathbb Z, M)\to\mathbb R$?  Are such beasts still ever called cochains?

Any relevant references and recommended reading much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complex you define is a special case of the complex $$C^*(X;G)$$ of maps of groups $C_n(X;\Bbb Z)\to G$ defined generally for any topological space $X$ and abelian group $G$ (your example being of course $G=\Bbb R$). Its elements are called "$G$-valued cochains on $X$", and the associated cohomology groups are called *cohomology with coefficients in $G$*.

Comment: Thanks very much for this Olivier.  Would you mind pointing me to a reference that discusses this stuff; I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: You could look at Allen Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology* (freely available on his website). He discusses this thoroughly, in particular how to calculate the corresponding cohomology groups from the standard cohomology groups.

Comment: Josh, look at universal coefficient theorems for the homology/cohomology.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Thanks again.

Comment: @TedShifrin I most certainly will, especially since you're the second person who's suggested that to me, the first being a math grad student.  I as a theoretical physics grad just learning this stuff, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

If $M$ is a $\Bbb Z$-module, then $\text{Hom}(M,\Bbb R)\cong\text{Hom}(M,\Bbb Z)\otimes \mathbb R$. Integrating any $k$-form over a (smooth) chain gives a practical such "real" cochain.

Comment: I think your isomorphism is wrong...

Comment: Oy, @Olivier :) What stupidity have I committed?

Comment: Consider $M=\bigoplus_{\Bbb N}\Bbb Z$, then the linear map $e_n\mapsto\sqrt{n}$ does not belong to $\mathrm{Hom}(M,\Bbb Z)\otimes\Bbb R$ : $\mathrm{Hom}(M,\Bbb Z)\otimes\Bbb R$ is a strict submodule of $\mathrm{Hom}(M,\Bbb R)$.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking finitely-generated might be needed.

Comment: @TedShifrin As a matter of terminology, would you happen to know if elements of $\mathrm{Hom}(M,\mathbb R)$ are ever referred to as cochains when $M$ is the $\mathbb Z$-module of chains?  The $k$-form example you gave is precisely what I had in mind when I wrote this question; such objects arise naturally in physics (especially thermodynamics when modeling heat).  By the way, I'm a fan of "multivariable mathematics," so I was, I must admit, somewhat star-struck when I saw your answer.